# Auto send userA's profile URL to userB

Tags: users

I thought this could be easy, but I don't know what's the best way to achieve this.

I have an acting "job" application site, userA need to finish his "profile2" first which including photos, weight, height etc..  userB will post a job node, then userA will click an "apply" button within the job node, userB will receive a message/email which including the userA's profile URL, then userB can look at userA's profile to decide if this person is ok for his job. I can't figure out which module I should use to make this process works, email/webform/privatemessage ? if you can suggest how to make this works. thanks

Answer (score 1):

You could build a flow like this using the [Flag module](https://www.drupal.org/project/flag).

General steps

1. Create a flag, **Apply for job** that targets the job node entity.  Make it a per-user flag, not a global flag.
2. Give job applicants permission to flag job nodes.
3. Create a view that show's the job poster all the flags on their job node, and use a relationship to pull in each applicant's profile.

Comment: thanks it works

Comment: @lee You're welcome.  On *Drupal Answers* and other Stack Exchange network sites, you don't need to say thanks; instead, if the answer solves your problem, you can click the checkmark to "accept" the answer and mark your question as solved.  This is the Stack Exchange network way of saying thanks.